# Want to select a css path, but same selector occurs multiple times

Tags: python, css, scrapy

From: https://www.funda.nl/en/koop/veenendaal/huis-42657821-roggeveld-59/ I want to select the living area and plot size through CSS selector.

Therefore, I have found the following css path:

```
response.css('span.kenmerken-highlighted__value.fd-text--nowrap').xpath('normalize 
space()')
```

When I do this, i get the following output:

```
[<Selector xpath='normalize-space()' data='123 m²'>, <Selector xpath='normalize-space()' data='187 m²'>, <Selector xpath='normalize-space()' data='4'>]
```

This is because multiple values on the website have the same css path. What do I have to do if I want to specify for example the 187 m2, or the '4'?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the below xpath selectors

```py
>>> response.xpath("//*[@title='plot size']/following-sibling::span[1]/text()").get()
'187 m²'
>>> response.xpath("//*[@title='bedrooms']/following-sibling::span[1]/text()").get()
'4'
```

For css selectors you can use the below

```py
>>> response.css("[title='plot size'] + span ::text").get()
'187 m²'
>>> response.css("[title='bedrooms'] + span ::text").get()
'4'
```